# magento 2 list colors and sizes of the product programmatically

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am working on `Mageneto 2.1.7` to create custom modules creating to create a rest API, I am trying to list the products with its available colors and sizes but I can't get it, I am using the following code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')->addAttributeToSelect([
                'name',
                'price',
                'image',
                'color',
                'size',
            ]);
    $output = '';
    foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
        $output .= \Zend_Debug::dump($product->debug(), null, false);
    }
    var_dump($output);
```

I got all the data but not getting the sizes and colors as I need to list it.
the following is the output I got

```html
<pre>
array(11) {
  ["entity_id"] => string(1) "1"
  ["attribute_set_id"] => string(1) "4"
  ["type_id"] => string(12) "configurable"
  ["sku"] => string(2) "p1"
  ["has_options"] => string(1) "1"
  ["required_options"] => string(1) "1"
  ["created_at"] => string(19) "2017-07-05 08:13:31"
  ["updated_at"] => string(19) "2017-07-10 11:25:27"
  ["name"] => string(2) "p1"
  ["image"] => string(125) "/f/a/fashion-womens-clothing-to-give-you-fresh-ideas-in-creating-your-own-fashion-clothes-so-it-looks-more-astounding-3_1.jpg"
  ["price"] => string(6) "1.0000"
}
array(11) {
  ["entity_id"] => string(1) "2"
  ["attribute_set_id"] => string(1) "4"
  ["type_id"] => string(6) "simple"
  ["sku"] => string(2) "p2"
  ["has_options"] => string(1) "0"
  ["required_options"] => string(1) "0"
  ["created_at"] => string(19) "2017-07-06 11:54:37"
  ["updated_at"] => string(19) "2017-07-06 11:54:37"
  ["name"] => string(2) "p2"
  ["image"] => string(38) "/i/l/il201702160307496471t_300x400.jpg"
  ["price"] => string(6) "1.0000"
}
array(12) {
  ["entity_id"] => string(1) "3"
  ["attribute_set_id"] => string(1) "4"
  ["type_id"] => string(7) "virtual"
  ["sku"] => string(9) "p1-purpel"
  ["has_options"] => string(1) "0"
  ["required_options"] => string(1) "0"
  ["created_at"] => string(19) "2017-07-09 06:49:56"
  ["updated_at"] => string(19) "2017-07-09 06:49:56"
  ["name"] => string(9) "p1-purpel"
  ["image"] => string(45) "/0/0/0009fb829de5ced795d1ed509e58866b_1_2.jpg"
  ["price"] => string(6) "1.0000"
  ["color"] => string(1) "4"
}
</pre>
```

Comment: Is sizes and colors set as "Use in product listing" in the Magento backend? otherwise you wont be able to get them in a sql statement.

Comment: yes the  "Use in product listing" is set to Yes

Comment: What about this: "Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront" set to yes?

Comment: set to yes also

Comment: I see  ["color"] => string(1) "4" of sku:p1-purpel

Comment: yes i want to list all the available colors of the product